# want to retrieve value from an array using java

Tags: java

I have an array like this:
[Version{self=https://tms.something.com/rest/api/2/version/23152, id=23152, name=RB_8.0.2, description=RB_8.0.2, isArchived=false, isReleased=true, releaseDate=2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:30}]
this array is the result of a method that is supported by jira-rest-java-api which is getAffectedVersions. 
I want to retrieve only the name i.e. RB_8.0.2 from this and want to get it printed
My object name is issueDetails1 and issueDetails1.getAffectedVersions gives the above array as result
I tried quite a lot of things like:

```
    Set<String> lists = issueDetails1.getSubComponents();
    String[] stringArray = lists.toArray(new String[lists.size()]);
    int size = lists.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(((JSONArray) lists).get(2));
    }
```

Can you please suggest some other way?

Comment: this gives me nullPointerException, can somebody suggest how to go about this?

Comment: @pzaenger sorry i didn't got you, can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Why do you have a loop with the value i, if you actually never use i?

Comment: I am not getting when you say I don't use "i"

Comment: you have a for-loop which counts till size with counter i. normally you use i then to access something from the array

Comment: Why do you even use a for loop??

Couldn't you just System.out.println(lists.get(2))...why the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You're clearly trying to parse a Json while your cast to JSONARRAY suggests you already have a library able to do this.

I'd advise you to read about your json library and use it.

However, for the simple case you wanted, that should do the trick :

```
String theNameYouWanted = list.stream().filter(e -> e != null && e.contains("name=")).map(string -> string.replace("name=", "")).findAny().orElse("not found");
```

Comment: Sorry to say but still I get nullPointerException again

Comment: I edited the filter to prevent null items. However I believe it's rather your Set lists which is null, which is your responsibility (or even somewhere else in your code, which is all the more your duty to check it for null beforehand).